# How do I increase the logging level for Puma?

Tags: web-server, logging, ruby-on-rails

Currently I am only getting ActiveRecord and view-rendering output in my Rails application log file, since I switched to Puma from WEBrick.  I haven't been able to find where I can modify the output level of Puma's logging.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at the configuration.rb settings?  It looks like you can send the standard error and out to a file.

Answer (score 2):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels:

> The available log levels are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`,
>   and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5
>   respectively. To change the default log level, use
>
> ```
> config.log_level = :warn # In any environment initializer, or
> Rails.logger.level = 0   # at any time
> ```
>
> This is useful when you want to log under development or staging, but
>   you don't want to flood your production log with unnecessary
>   information.
>
> The default Rails log level is `debug` in all environments